# How to get Date as a segment in Final_URL_Report in Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

Executing my code (using the Google Adwords Library to build an oauth user etc) works when using a query with Month as a segment

> String query = "SELECT EffectiveFinalUrl, Cost, Clicks, Impressions,
>   Month FROM FINAL_URL_REPORT";

But it aggregates across all time, split into months. I am trying to pull in the data as daily aggregates. The documentation has both Month and Date (splitting data into yyyy-MM-dd) as a segment you can include in the query, but Date does not work.

> String query = "SELECT EffectiveFinalUrl, Cost, Clicks, Impressions,
>   Date FROM FINAL_URL_REPORT";

Results in Error 400: Bad Request.

Am I missing something in the documentation that tells me how to resolve this?

[Adwords Final_URL_Report Documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/final-url-report#date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set a date range by adding something like DURING ... to your query.

Comment: Found this moments before you answered. Hidden deep in the documentation (i believes i was rereading turning XML into string) where it states "You can removing duration all_time for all queries unless you are using date, which requires a date range. Why this isnt under the segmentation section, or under the date segment I cant say.